# Flex-direction row and justify-content: flex-start not working

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I want to display a formula that on hover over certain text displays a `div`/message. I want my divs to display as a row, so the content should read as:

```
P(1 + R/N)nt
```

Right now they display as a column:

```
P
(1 +
R/
N)
n
t
```

This is my code:

```
<div key="4">
                <b>How did we get these numbers?</b>
                <div className="equation">
                    <div>
                        <div
                            className="eq"
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                            P
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            className="eq"
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                            (1 +
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            className="eq"
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                            R/
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            className="eq"
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                            N)
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                          <sup>n</sup>
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
                            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
                        >
                          <sup>t</sup>
                        </div>
                        {this.state.isHovering && <div>example hover text</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My emotion CSS styling:

```
const equation = css`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
`;
```

This is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-pl9m3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your styled component syntax for the 'equation' css class is wrong. If you inspect your page, you'll notice the css for class equation is not being applied to your parent div. The right syntax is something like this:

```
<Equation>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  ...
</Equation>

const Equation = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
`;
```

Working sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/emotion-xupvk